# Is there a way to externally automate vs code?

Tags: automation, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to externally automate vs code?

I realize that you can make extensions in vs code with java script.

But is there a way to invoke the vs code apis externally ( ie from c# )?

For example from c# I can externally automate word, outlook, visual studio by using the running object table and com interfaces.  I doubt visual studio code has a COM interface :)

Comment: There are [certain options you can pass to the command line](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line). There is also an open issue for allowing [extensions to provide additional command-line hooks](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/37383). Because VS Code is cross-platform, I think that anything beyond that will be impractical.